# Can Terraform mention multiple module instances in one resource?

Tags: terraform

In Terraform is there some way to refer to the set of instances of a module?

I have several workloads that each need very similar (but still separate) infrastructure, and I also want to configure another item of infrastructure to be used in common between them.

For example, say each needs several pieces of infrastructure (AWS S3 bucket, SQS queue, and IAM role..) but with mostly equivalent attributes. I want to achieve this without code duplication (e.g., by writing a Terraform module to be reused for each instance, with input variables for name prefixes and specific IAM policies).

Is there a Terraform syntax for then making a reference to all of those instances in a single resource, and with minimal boilerplate? (Maybe something analogous to a *classmethod*, to define a common resource to only be created once, even if multiple instances of that module get created?) For example, to make a shared kubernetes config-map that contains an index of the generated addresses (bucket names or SQS URLs), as a mechanism for passing those addresses to the containerised workloads that will use them? Another example might be setting up a single load balancer or DNS server with rules referring individually to every service from this group.

Or does the problem have to be approached in the other direction, by starting with a list of parameter sets, and somehow looping over that list to create the infrastructure? (Requiring every instance of this kind to be specified together in the same file?)

Answer (score 0):

The Terraform terminology for modularity is a *child module* that is *called* from multiple places in the *configuration*. The call uses the `module` block (where parameter values are passed). Since modules are directories, the child module will be defined somewhere outside of the configuration root module directory tree. The calling module can access *output values* exported from the child module.

You can use a single module call to create multiple instances, by putting a `for_each` argument in the `module` block, and passing a *map* (or *set*) through this meta-argument. The other argument expressions in the block can use the `each` object to refer to the particular `for_each` element corresponding to the current instance, as Terraform iterates through them. From outside of the module block (elsewhere in the calling module), the output values can themselves be accessed like a map.

You can use `[for .. in .. : .. if ..]` *expressions* to filter and transform maps. (Some transformations can also be performed more concisely by *splat expressions*.) Some resources (such as `kubernetes_config_map`) have arguments that take maps directly. (Also, some data or resources can accept a sequence of nested blocks, which can be generated from a map by using *dynamic* block syntax.)

---

Note, do not use the older feature `count` as an alternative to `for_each`. Otherwise, there is a [documented](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count#when-to-use-for_each-instead-of-count) tendency to produce unintended destruction and recreation of other infrastructure if one element of the list has to be decommissioned. Similarly, passing a list-derived set, instead of a map, to `for_each` can make indexing more cumbersome.

---

Thus for the OP's example, the approach would be to first create a parameterised child module defining the nearly-duplicated parts of the infrastructure (e.g., bucket, queue, role, etc). Make sure the child module has either inputs or outputs for any aspect that needs customisation (for example, output a handle for the created bucket resource, or at least for its auto-generated globally-unique name). Then have a module in your configuration that creates your whole collection of instances (by a single `module` block that sources the child module and using `for_each`). The customisation of individual instances (e.g., some having additional policies or other specific infrastructure) can be achieved by a combination of the parameter sets initially passed to the call, and supplementary `resource` blocks that each refer to outputs from an individual instance. Furthermore, the outputs can also be referred to collectively, for example parsing the module call outputs to form a list of bucket names (or addresses) and then passing this list to another resource (i.e., to a k8s config map). Again this must be done from the calling module; the child module does not have access to a list of instances of itself.